# Where gnome-system-monitor save its setttings?

Tags: gnome, kde

For example, https://userbase.kde.org/KSysGuard save its setting on `/home/user/.config/ksysguardrc`.

Where https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SystemMonitor save its settings?

There are no settings files on `.config` or `.gnome`.

I opened [`fatrace`](https://piware.de/2012/02/fatrace-report-system-wide-file-access-events/) and ran `gnome-system-monitor`, but it did not seem to read any settings file:

```
panel-1-whisker(4901): RO /usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor
panel-1-whisker(4901): R /usr/bin/gnome-system-monitor
gnome-system-mo(4901): O /usr/share/gnome-system-monitor/gsm.gresource
gnome-system-mo(4901): RCO /usr/share/applications/gnome-system-monitor.desktop
gnome-system-mo(4901): RCO /usr/share/applications/gnome-system-monitor-kde.desktop
```

Comment: It is very likely that it uses dconf/gsettings. You can try to check with `gsettings list-recursively | grep system-monitor`.

Comment: @N0rbert, Thanks, it worked! But how can I save these settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use corresponding scheme from dconf/gsettings.

Discover exact names with `gsettings list-recursively | grep system-monitor` and then you can save the output to file and add `gsettings set` to start of each line.

For example:

```
org.gnome.system-monitor.something param 0
```

will change to

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system-monitor.something param 0
```

---

Or use `dconf dump /org/gnome/system-monitor > file` to save
and `dconf load /org/gnome/system-monitor < file` to restore.

Comment: `dconf dump /org/gnome/system-monitor/` outputs nothing on 22.04?