# where are system-monitor-next extension's settings stored? or how to make it work again? for 22.04

Tags: 22.04, settings, gnome-shell-extension, system-monitor

The systray indicator is important as it is small and I can keep it always visible.
What I always need to monitor is (in this order of importance): iowait, disk write, cpu usage, disk read, network upload, network download.

on 22.04, only https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3010/system-monitor-next/ was working  well, until it vanished.

So I think I need to clean/reset w/e it configured, to try to make it work again, because no matter what I do: try other versions, disable/enable, restart gnome-shell with it uninstalled/instelledAgain... Nothing works, it wont show up again, and I used it a lot :(

On that homepage (using "Google Chrome"), I click uninstall, then I see this folder be deleted:
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/system-monitor-next@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
But when I reinstall it and that folder is filled up again, nothing changes, it wont show up the the systray top bar.

So, do you know how to clean it up to try to make it fresh work again?

These did not help:
[Where are gnome extensions preferences stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178580/where-are-gnome-extensions-preferences-stored) (as I removed and extracted the extension again from downloaded file and nothing changed)
[Where gnome-system-monitor save its setttings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169188/where-gnome-system-monitor-save-its-setttings) (it is not really about the extension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 22.04 the default Firefox web browser is now a snap and the GNOME Shell Extensions no longer functions.

There are a few alternatives... replace the snap with the APT version of Firefox to continue using your old favourites using the [instructions here](https://fostips.com/ubuntu-21-10-two-firefox-remove-snap/) or install `Extension Manager` following [these instructions](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/manage-gnome-extensions-ubuntu-2204/)

There is also the application `Stacer` which is available from `Ubuntu Software` which I use and I think pretty much matches what you are looking for.

[image]

The range of extensions in Extension Manager are being constantly added to so if your chosen one is not there just now, it could be included some time soon.

Comment: as a side note ... `google-chrome` will still work as it is still installed by APT from a DEB package.

Comment: The systray indicator is important as it is small and I can keep it always visible. What I always need to monitor is (in this order of importance): iowait, disk write, cpu usage, disk read, network upload, network download. Also, I did it all using "Google Chrome". But I will check the extensions manager, thx.

Comment: yes! `extension-manager` of the package "gnome-shell-extension-manager" did the trick! The moment I click on the title bar enable button, the system monitors showed up all again! I will just wait a few boots see if it keeps working (even if I need to use the manager again), as that was the problem I had initially and found no other workaround, thx!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer so that it will be easy for someone else with the same issue to find it. Thanks.